# How to extend Panache with static method?

Tags: quarkus

> Hello. I want to write a static method in class with @MapperdSupperclass. such as findByName. so the child object can use method to query itself.
> But I got error. **It will query BaseUpdatableEntity not the childObject.The code like this**.

```java
@MappedSuperclass
@Slf4j
@ToString
public abstract class BaseUpdatableEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @Getter
    protected LocalDateTime created;

    @Getter
    protected LocalDateTime updated;

    @Getter
    protected String createdBy;

    @Getter
    protected String updatedBy;

    @Version
    @Setter
    @Getter
    protected Long lockVersion = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void prePersist() {
        super.prePersist();
        created = LocalDateTime.now();
        createdBy = MDCScope.getUsername();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void preUpdate() {
        updated = LocalDateTime.now();
        updatedBy = MDCScope.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        BaseUpdatableEntity updatableEntity = (BaseUpdatableEntity) super.clone();
        updatableEntity.setLockVersion(1L);
        return updatableEntity;
    }

    public BaseUpdatableEntity getByName(String name) {
        return find("name", name).<BaseUpdatableEntity>singleResultOptional().orElse(null);
    }
}
```

so I read the **PanacheEntityBase** code. I find the static method with *@GenerateBridge*
But I don't konw how to archive it with myself?

Comment: I am pretty sure that what you are trying to do won't work

Comment: Yes, I know. i just want to know the panache how to bytes enchancement in build time let it works.
The PanacheEntityBase already works. So I want to study it.

Comment: The basic idea is that the class is transformed at build time. You can start by checking out: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/2.8.0.Final/extensions/panache/panache-common/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkus/panache/common/deployment/visitors/PanacheEntityClassOperationGenerationVisitor.java#L42

Comment: Yes. I had study how to enhance it now. Thanks a lot.